# Restrict the size of pushed view controller to the container view controller

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I am implementing filters in my ecommerce iOS app. I want my filter functionality similar to **ebay** filter functionality.

Like in the gif attached when user taps on sort filter, the next view (maybe a view controller) opens and shows possible sort options. I am trying to replicate this functionality.

[image]

**What i tried.**

I have implemented a container view controller in which i am showing the filter options. when user taps on any filter item, i am performing a push segue(using storyboard) to next view controller in which i am showing relevant filter options

**But the problem.**

When i tap on any filter item to proceed further, my app opens the next view controller in full screen, not in the bounds of the container view controller.

See the gif

[image]

**So how to restrict the next view controller's frame to its parent container view controller?**

Also the height of the next view controller should be equal to the number of items in it. See the ebay filters gif. (This is secondary requirement)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the container of first screen in filter?

Comment: and what are you using to show next screen when you show the inner filter

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar my side panel is a container view controller which i am showing and hiding through animation.

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I am using push segue through storyboard for showing inner filter

Comment: try the following approach

Comment: Ok. Let me give it a try

Comment: Cool keep me posted does it work or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest your view hierarchy should be like as follows.

Embed your container view controller (main filter screen) inside a navigation controller by going into editor (xcode menu) ==> embed in ==> Navigation Controller (story board should be open).

On didSelect method of container view controller, push your inner filter Controller by either storyboard segue or programmatically.

[image]

Comment: you mean to embed my inner filter VC in a navigation controller ?

Comment: yes so all the screens in the filter would be embeded in the navigationcontroller

Comment: still figuring out.

Comment: Worked. Finally. But with a little difference. 

Actually i had to embed my container view controller (first VC) inside a UINavigation controller. so the navigation controller appears before the container view controller. So the heirarchy that worked is 

UINavigation Controller ==> Container View Controller (First Filter Screen) ==> Second Filter Screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165833/discussion-between-awais-fayyaz-and-harshal-bhavsar).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the view controller that wants to present define a [presentation context](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext), and then on the other view controller, make the [presentation overCurrentContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/1621507-overcurrentcontext). That should make the other view controller present itself only over the context of the parent.

This is the similar presentation style that is used on popovers.

Comment: i have set the presentation context of first view controller (my side container view) to true in viewdid load. Now how can i do this part ? "on the other view controller, make the presentation overCurrentContext."

Comment: Change the modalPresentationStyle of the presenting viewController.